# Refresh data of react app from backend every 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How do I refresh my react app every 2 seconds?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Route, Switch, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';

function App() {
    const location = useLocation();
    console.log(location);
    const [feedbacks, setFeedbacks] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchArticles = async () => {
            setFeedbacks([]);

            const url = 'https://url.abc.com/';
            const api_response = await fetch(url);
            let data = await api_response.json();

            setFeedbacks(data);
        }

        fetchArticles();
    }, [])

    const data = {feedbacks};

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" render={() => <Home data={data}/>} exact/>
                <Route path="/:username" render={() => <Home data={data}/>} exact/>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `setInterval();` on `fetchArticles`? Something like:

```
setInterval(fetchArticles(), 2000)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a JS function for intervals "setInterval" run the function you pass in a regular interval in ms.

This should work:

```
const fetchArticles = async () => {
    setFeedbacks([]);
    const url = 'https://url.abc.com/';
    const api_response = await fetch(url);
    let data = await api_response.json();
    setFeedbacks(data);
}

useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(fetchArticles(), 2000)
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 useEffect(() => {

 const fetchArticles = async () => {
   setFeedbacks([]);
   const url = 'https://url.abc.com/';
   const api_response = await fetch(url);
   let data = await api_response.json();
   setFeedbacks(data);
 }

       setInterval(fetchArticles(), 2000)
 }, [])
```